# Inverse Fourier Transform and operator of multiplication by $\chi_{B_r(0)}$ in Sobolev space $H_{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^m)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $r>0$. I need to show that there is a constant $C>0$ such that 
$$||u- u_r||_{k} \leq \frac{C}{r}||u||_{k+1}$$ 
for all $u$ in the Sobolev space $H^{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^m)$, where $$u_r:=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[M_r \mathcal{F}[u]],$$
$M_r$ is the operator of multiplication by the characteristic function of the ball $B_r(0)$, $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier Transform and $||\cdot||_{k}$ is the norm in $H^k(\mathbb{R}^m)$ .

I tried to derive $u_r$, but I am stuck. I don't understand what is the relation between $u$ and $u_r$.

Can you help me?

Comment: You don't have to compute the Fourier multiplier this should follow from the definition of the $H^k$ norm as $||\langle \xi \rangle ^k \hat{f}(\xi)||_{L^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that one way to define the $H^k$ norm is by
$$||u||_{H^k}=  ||\langle\xi \rangle^{k} \hat{u}(\xi)||_{L^2}$$
Where $\langle \xi \rangle = \sqrt{1 + |\xi|^2}$. Making use of this we write
$$\begin{align}||u-u_r||_{H^k}^2 &= ||\langle \xi\rangle^k[\hat{u - u_r}]||_{L^2}^2\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \langle \xi \rangle ^{2k}(1 - \chi_{B_r(0)})\hat{u}^2(\xi)d\xi\\
&= \int _{\mathbb{R}^m\setminus B_r(0)} \langle \xi \rangle^{2k}\hat{u}(\xi)^2 d\xi\\
&= \int _{\mathbb{R}^m\setminus B_r(0)} \frac{\langle \xi \rangle^{2k+2}}{\langle \xi \rangle^{2}} \hat{u}(\xi)^2 d\xi \\
&\leq \frac{1}{r^2}||u||_{H^{k+1}}^2
\end{align}$$